# haskell, how to deal with mismatched types - monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I can't deal with following problem:
I have some function, that return `foo :: a -> b -> ErrorT String IO Int`
I know that it returns `IO (Either String Int)`.
Nevertheless, I have also more complex function, that returns:

`bar :: a -> b ->   StateT Char (ReaderT Char (ErrorT String IO)) Int`

This function `bar` calls function `foo`. I am going to to following thing:
If `foo` called `throwError` `bar` also throws the same error.  If `foo` returns `Int` `bar` also returns `Int`.

However, it is possible due to mismatch types.

I dont know how to do this in elegant way.
I think that my order of transformator monad is not ok.

Comment: can you please add an example where you *call* `foo` inside `bar` - you probably just need the right *lift*?

Comment: yeah, thanks you very much. I used `lift $ lift $ ` and compiler accpeted it.  I didnt know about it - I thought that lift will be done in automatic way.

Comment: well that would make using monad-stacks a lot easier ;) - but never mind - maybe you want to write your own answer or close the question when it's solved for you

Comment: Instead of using concrete types, it would probaly make more sense to use `MonadState`, `MonadReader` and `MonadError` - that way you don't have to `lift`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
bar x y = do
  -- some code
  z <- lift $ lift $ foo x y
  -- some more code
  return z
```

Answer (score 2):

What I typically do is using what I've dubbed *Transformer Monad Classes*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State

inner :: ReaderT Char IO Int
inner = do
    a <- ask
    lift $ print a
    return 5

inner' :: (MonadReader Char m, MonadIO m) => m Int
inner' = do
    a <- ask
    liftIO $ print a
    return 5

outer :: StateT Char (ReaderT Char IO) Int
outer = do
    a <- get

    b <- lift $ inner    -- need to lift
    c <- inner'          -- no need to lift

    lift . lift $ print "need to lift twice to get to IO"            

    return 5

main = runReaderT (runStateT outer 'b') 'a'
```

Let's break it down; the first `inner` function has a concrete type you need to directly lift to in order to use it. However, if you parametrize it leaving only *capabilities* in the signature, you can skip the lifting, as long as it's unambiguous in the stack where to get this capability. In this case it's clear, because `StateT Char (ReaderT Char IO) Int` has exactly one instance for `MonadIO` (from `IO`) and exactly one instance of `MonadReader Char` (from `ReaderT ... Char`).

Now, it doesn't matter *how many lifts* you need to make, as long as the instance is clear! Consider:

```
outer' :: ErrorT String (StateT Char (ReaderT Char IO)) Int
outer' = do
    a <- inner'               -- still no need to lift!
    b <- lift . lift $ inner  -- need to double lift in this case
    return 5
```

The last thing that might not be obvious is that the signature of `outer` could be expressed in a generic way as well:

```
outer :: (MonadState Char m, MonadReader Char m, MonadIO m) => m Int
```

And it would still work without any lifts (well sans `liftIO` for IO operations, because functions like `print` are defined in terms of `IO`, not `MonadIO m`. In comparison, functions like `ask` and `get` are defined in terms of the respective `MonadX` class which allows us to skip the lifting).